# Editing SSRS 2005 Reports in VS 2008

Tags: deployment, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have an old Report Server Project created in Visual Studio 2005. The reports are deployed to an SSRS 2005 Server.

When I open this project in Visual Studio 2008 it converts the project file and then when I try and deploy any of the reports (from Visual Studio 2008) I encounter this error:

**The report definition is not valid.  Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.**

Is there anyway I can edit and deploy my report files in Visual Studio 2008 without upgrading them. This would save me having to install Visual Studio 2005 on my new laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way of editing SQL 2005 Report files with VS 2008. That's why we still have VS 2005 installed here.